# How deleting a specific record from table using an list box

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i create a list box that show table records and a delete button in access form

i want when user select an item from list box and click on delete button

with SQL code delete related item that selected in list box

i find some code like this:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "DELETE FROM Tbl_DCC WHERE Text_AgnetName = " & Me.List_DCC.Column(0) &" and "& Me.List_DCC.Column(2)
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me.List_DCC.Requery
```

But it Does not work
I am thankful with your guidance

Answer (score 2):

try to put single quotes in the where clause

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "DELETE FROM Tbl_DCC WHERE Text_AgnetName = '" & Me.List_DCC.Column(0) &"' and '"& Me.List_DCC.Column(2) & "'"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
Me.List_DCC.Requery
```